# Strange deadlock situation in ASP.NET Core Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, task-parallel-library, deadlock

In my ASP.NET Core application I have a a seemingly very simple action. It awaits some value from an asynchronous method and then returns it as an OK-result:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetNextCommand()
{
    var command = await LongPollManager.Instance.GetNextCommand(HttpContext.RequestAborted);
    return Ok(command);
}
```

When I call this route with some HTTP client I can verify in the debugger that this asynchronous method returns the desired value and passes it to the Ok method:

[image]

If I let the debugger continue I would expect to get the result in my HTTP client. But the client never receives a response.

When I then break the debugger I can see that the thread is blocked on some internal lock. You can see this in the current screenshot:

[image]

This behavior can be seen only since I made some changes in my `LongPollManager` class (which is actually quite complex and uses `TaskCompletionSource`s and `ConcurrentDictionarie`s, and `SemaphoreSlim`s internally).

The thing that puzzles me is that it's actually not my own `GetNextCommand` method which is blocking, but the blocking seems to happen inside ASP.NET Core. Once execution is in line 29 and I got my `command` object, all the complicated asynchronous stuff of my `LongPollManager` class is over and I don't see how anything I change in `LongPollManager` can prevent ASP.NET Core from properly finishing the request.

What could it be that ASP.NET Core is waiting here for? How can my code (which runs to line 29 without a deadlock) cause such a deadlock situation?

Comment: How is the client making the call

Comment: The client is another process on the same machine doing a HTTP GET on that route.

Comment: Is the model being returned a POCO or are there any knock on effects that are invoked when serializing it.

Comment: Good point - it used to contain only `string`s and `bool`s. But with my latest changes it also contains a public `Task` property. Do you think this could have any side-effects when ASP.NET Core tries to serialize it?

Comment: Yes it will. because it will try to invoke the property to get the value to serialize. And as it is a Task with will most likely try to serialize `Task.Result` synchronously which would lead to your dead lock.

Comment: That was it! I made the `Task` field private and made the task accessible via a public method. Now everything works as it should. Thanks a lot for your help!! Feel free to formulate your solution as an answer so that I can accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments

> But with my latest changes it also contains a public `Task` property. Do you think this could have any side-effects when ASP.NET Core tries to serialize it?

Yes it will.

The framework will try to invoke the property to get the value for serialization. And as the property returns a `Task`, will most likely try to serialize the task's `.Result` property synchronously which would lead to your dead lock.

Mixing async and blocking calls like `.Result` and `.Wait()` can cause deadlocks and should be avoided.

Reference [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Actions should return simple POCOs that have no side effects when serialized.

The public `Task` property should be hidden from the serailizer, ignored via attributes or should be converted to methods that do not get invoked when the model is serialized.